# How does MEAN.js automatically load routes?

Tags: routes, meanjs

I was reading the [Mean.JS](http://meanjs.org/) docs, and regarding routes, it says that to create routes just create a `.js` file similar to one of the pre-defined route files and Express [will automatically use it](http://meanjs.org/docs.html#folder-structure).

How does that magic happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that in the `config\express.js` file, there is this section:

```
    // Globbing routing files
    config.getGlobbedFiles('./app/routes/**/*.js').forEach(function(routePath) {
        require(path.resolve(routePath))(app);
    });
```

which passes a `glob` path (i.e. `'./app/routes/**/*.js'`) to the `getGlobbedFiles()` function and then calls a function (i.e. `foreach`) on each of the files returned in an array. Each file returned is one of the route files in the `routes` folder.

All routers are therefore `require`d into the app.